# Displaying auto resize width table as a pop up windows

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, jquery-ui

I have a form and in the form there is a button whereby when I click on it, it will shown a pop up windows which consist of a looping table. It means that the table do not have a fixed width but have a fixed height. 
Basically my question is how do I achieve this result so that the pop up windows will auto-resizing accordingly to the content of the table without the user have to adjust it. I have try and check the [perfectpopups](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/perfectPopups.html)

> Resizing the popups to fit non-image content of unknown width

but i couldn't get it to work in my page. I am a bit slow on this.

Here is a picture shots on how I would like it to be.
[image: pic1]

fyi. everytime there is a new data then this table will be shown underneath. How do I make it so that it will not shown underneath. Scroll horizontal also fine if that is the solution as long as it will not jump to below when there is new data. Basically this is how the table look like.
[image]

html

```
<input type="button" value="Condition" onClick="window.open('{% url Condition_view dept_id patient_NO %}', '', 'width=500, height=200, menubar=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=yes, status=0, titlebar=0, toolbar=0')">
```

Please help. What is the best solution for my case? I am open to all solution as long as it can be use in django. I am a fresher in this case.Any help will be very much appreciated. thank you.

Edited question

my html table from {% url Condition_view dept_id patient_NO %} page

```
<body>

{% if conditioner%}
<div id ="patient_table" style="clear:both">
<form action="." method="post" onsubmit=""> 
{% csrf_token %}
<table border="1" id="thetable">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Person_ID {{ patient_CPR }}</th>
  <th>Smoker</th>
  <th>Weight</th>
  <th>Height</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for condition in conditioner %}
{% with "#CCE6FF" as bgcolor%} 
<tr>
   <td style="height: 30">{{ condition.NEW_DATE }}</td>
   <td>
   <select class="SMOKER" name="condition">
   <option value="{{condition.smoker.0.0}}"
   {% if condition.SMOKER == condition.smoker.0.0 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>Never</option>
       <option value="{{condition.smoker.1.0}}" 
       {% if condition.SMOKER == condition.smoker.1.0 %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>Ex-smoker</option>
       </select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="condition" id="condition{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ condition.WEIGHT }}" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="condition" id="condition{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ condition.HEIGHT }}" /></td>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
 </div>

 {% else %}
 <p>No patient.</p>
 {% endif %}

 </body>
```

Hopefully with this information somebody can help me to solve my issue. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onClick` to call a function so you can set the width within the function

HTML

```
<input onClick="openTableWindow('{% url Condition_view dept_id patient_NO %}')">
```

JS

```
function openTableWindow(url) {
    var windowWidth = /* get width of table*/
    var windowProperties = 'width=' + windowWidth + ', height=200, ......  toolbar=0';
    window.open(url, '', windowProperties);
}
```

Comment: thks @charlietfl. Will do that. sorry what you mean by `get width of table`. i am totally blank. can you give me sample code pls.

Comment: I made changes @charlietfl. When I use `var windowWidth = $('#thetable').width();` then it gives me the right height but nothing happen to width. Then I use by calling another function to calculate the width `var windowWidth = getWindowWidth('#thetable');` but it gives me full length of windows width. Here is the link of the function I use.[How to get real window width](http://mauzon.com/how-to-get-real-window-width/) . Pls verify this if there is anything that need to be change @charlietfl